# Auto Resize Background Image To Fit All Devices And Orientations Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am making some colorful themes for my iOS tabbed app using Swift 5 and Xcode 11. I have multiple themes with background images on them. These background images have the perfect aspect ratio for portrait orientation and hence, they work exactly how I want them to in portrait orientation:
[image]

But things go wonky when I put my device into the landscape:
[image]

The image duplicates. Is there any possible way I could solve this? I've read some other alike questions on StackOverflow, all to no results.

Here's part of my view controller's 'theme' function, which gets called every time the view loads or the view appears(these are just 2 of my themes):

```swift
func theme(){
        if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "like") == 1{
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.84, green:0.84, blue:0.84, alpha:1.0)
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.21, green:0.56, blue:0.96, alpha:1.0)
            view1.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.78, green:0.78, blue:0.78, alpha:1.0)
            ansView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            historyButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            for button in operatorButtons {
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            }
            for button in numberButtons {
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.53, green:0.52, blue:0.53, alpha:0.5)
            }
            equalButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.49, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.78, green:0.78, blue:0.78, alpha:1.0)
            view1.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        }else if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "like") == 2{
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.98, green:0.64, blue:0.02, alpha:1.0)
            view1.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Black-6")!)
            ansView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.53, green:0.52, blue:0.53, alpha:0.5)
            historyButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.9)
            for button in operatorButtons {
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.00, blue:0.00, alpha:0.9)
            }
            for button in numberButtons {
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.53, green:0.52, blue:0.53, alpha:0.5)
            }
            equalButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.53, green:0.52, blue:0.53, alpha:0.5)
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            view1.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        }
//more themes
    }
```

By the way, I have tried:

```swift
view1.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
```

And:

```swift
view1.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleToFill
```

Comment: I will use scaleAspectFill. The image will always stretch on one of the devices. AspectFill works the best.

Comment: @Josh I've tried that, but thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single image that will work for you in both portrait and landscape mode. You might have to implement an [adaptive design](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/).